# How to use a play and pause button for multiple audio on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, audio

Javascript:

```
<script>
/**
* jQuery document ready function (when the DOM is loaded)
* From here we can use $ to reference the jQuery object
*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
/**
* Finds all elements that have _BOTH_ the .audio and .controls classes
* then attaches a click handler to the .playpausebtn class
*/
$('.audio.controls').on('click', '.playpausebtn', function(e) {
/**
* $(this) refers to the element that the event has fired on, in this case its the
* .playpausebtn that you clicked on (not any of the others)
*
* $(this).parent() will target the parent element, then inside the parent element we want to
* find the `audio` element
*
* Using the array key [0] should access the element directly, rather than the set of matched elements
*/
audio = $(this).parent().find('audio')[0];
if ( audio.paused ) {
audio.play();
$(this).css( 'background', 'url("Images/pause.png") no-repeat' );
} else {
audio.pause();
$(this).css( 'background', 'url("Images/play.png") no-repeat' );
}
});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
<audio class="audio" name="audio" src="Media/Beats/Catching waves/Catching Waves - [Prod. By Jordan Ace] - Preview Version.mp3"></audio>
<button class="playpausebtn"></button>
<button class="mutebtn"></button>
</div>
<div class="controls">
<audio class="audio" name="audio" src="Media/Beats/Coming up/Coming Up - [Prod. By Jordan Ace] - Preview Version.mp3"></audio>
<button class="playpausebtn"></button>
<button class="mutebtn"></button>
</div>
```

Unfortunately my audio is not playing at all, can someone help me out? I'm not sure where i've gone wrong. It will be used to play multiple tracks in a table on one page from my site.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial selector, `$('.audio.controls')` is wrong. It should be `$('.controls')`. That might help.

Comment: Changed it to $('.controls') and still nothing